# Is the following set empty?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
sp\left \{ 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
-1 \\ 
1 \\ 
-1
\end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix}
4\\ 
-2 \\ 
4 \\ 
-2
\end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}
 \right \} \bigcap \left \{ \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3\\
x_4 
\end{pmatrix} | \begin{matrix}
x_1 + x_2 = 0\\ 
x_3 = 2x_4
\end{matrix} \right \}$$

I was asked to find the basis of the following set but the vectors of the LHS set never fit to both requirements on the RHS set , or maybe I'm totally wrong and the binary relation between the requirements is **OR**?

Comment: im not 100% sure, but looks like that the LHS doesn't contain the null vector.

Comment: @Integral: The zero vector is in the span of any set of vectors.

Comment: The left hand side is linearly dependent.  Notice that $3 ( 1 , -1 , 1 , -1 ) = ( 4 , -2 , 4 , -2 ) - ( 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 )$

Comment: @Andrew: In fact it’s generated by $\langle 1,0,1,0\rangle^T$ and $\langle 0,1,0,1\rangle^T$.

Comment: Would you be so kind to change basis of the following set to "basis of the following subspace"? A set doesn't have basis. You need an inner product (or more) to have a basis or a generator.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott of course! I totally forgot the scalars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would interpret it as you did. It’s not empty, though: it’s the trivial subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ containing only the zero vector. (And while these objects are groups under vector addition, the fact that you’re talking about the span in the first term makes it clear that they are to be understood as vector spaces, not as groups.)

Comment: How do you know they are from $\mathbb{R}^4$? It could be $\mathbb{C}^4$ or a four dimensional vector space over any field. Just want to mention it:)

Comment: Assuming we're in $\mathbb{R}^4$, what's the basis of the following set? I know that $dim(\{0\}) = 0$ so it means there's no basis?

Comment: @Georgey: Yes, the basis is empty (or at least that’s how I’d express it).

Comment: Yes, the dimension of any space (in this case zero) is the cardinal of any basis (in this case, the empty set).

Answer (score 2):

A group does have a neutral element, hence it can't be empty. But you don't talk about groups at all. You talk about sets (or vector spaces), and this one does have the zero vector in it.

A basis for the Nullvectorspace is the empty set. 
Because the empty sum is defined to be the neutral element. And the neutral element of addition in a vectorspace is the null vector.

Comment: Yes, I translated the word sets incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

The set in your question consists of only the zero vector. This is a $0$-dimensional vector space, and the empty set is a basis of it.